# How Can i get the value of click element using XPATH in Web driver

Tags: xpath

Below is the Property of the field got from firebug

```
<td class="list-padding radar_text radar_left"> <a class="radar_button" href="/IPradar/update.htm?ticketID=3749" target="_blank">3749</a> </td>
```

Below is the XPath for the same

```
/html/body/center/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]/a
```

In my code i gave the following to get the value '3749'

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]/a")).getText();
```

The value 3749 is not constant, it will change dynamically

i want to fetch whatever value that comes in the place of <'3749'>

I am using selenium web driver

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not able to understand the Question, But i think u want to get the text where ticketID is 3749, for that You Can use following code to get the Desired Text

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'list-padding radar_text')]/a[contains(@href,'ticketID=3749')]")).getText()
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'list-padding radar_text')]/a[contains(@href,'ticketID')]")).getText()
```

Thanks

Comment: this answers my question, Have an another clarification. how i can  to fetch the value 3749 in between the "tagstarget="_blank">3749</a>" ?

Comment: Its Simple U can use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'list-padding radar_text')]/a[contains(@tagstarget,'blank')]")).getText(). Please accept the answer too. Thanks

Comment: Ur answer helped me a lot. Thanks a lot. Now i am facing another issue in fetching a data from a table. I want to fetch value from table. I am not sure whether it is exactly a table or not. Below is the property of one of the cell.             
 <td colspan="6">
<table class="radar_table">
<tbody>
<tr class="radar_odd">
<td class="list-padding radar_left" style="vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold; width: 50px;">Attachment Encoding:</td>
<td class="list-padding radar_left radar_text">base64</td>
</tr>

Comment: It is not having a name or id. So I tried to fetch the value 'Attachment Encoding:' using XPath. XPath for this is  "/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/th/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/span/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td" 
 what i gave in my code to fetch the value is "driver.findElement(By.xpath("MY XPATH")).getText();But this not returning any value